# Can't delete App ID, delete button grayed out

Tags: xcode

i'm developing an app through Xcode5. so it automatically created an App ID for my app. however, now i changed my app name and xcode created another App Id for my app. how can i delete the previous one? the delete button cannot be selected as it's grayed out. clicking it will cause the window to load and then show me the App ID, and yes the App ID is still there. is there any solution? BTW my app isn't connected/added to itunes Connect neither submitted to Apple yet.

Comment: Uhmm...did you tried to delete it from the organisator? How did you tried? Just in case you tried at developer.apple.com...maybe there is a problem. They had many problems in the last month. You should try that again later.

Comment: from the Xcode organizer no.. i looked up and couldn't find anything related. where should i look specifically? i checked the developer centre support section and it seems that others are also experiencing this after the update.

Comment: It should be fixed by itself. And you don't use you AppID anyways. So where is the problem. Just wait and it will be fixed soon by them.